# SVN: renaming in the Repo-browser while keeping Working Copy in sync

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've renamed a branch in the repo and carelessly kept working with the same working copy (that was checked out from that branch before the rename). When I later tried to commit, I've noticed the working copy is still targeting the old path. I want to commit the changes to the new path in the repo, while of course keeping history etc...

Do SVN has an elegant way around this?

I read about commands Switch and Relocate but I'm not sure any of them completely suits my problem (the scenarios described are different), and I've always been a bit frightened about trying out commands in the SVN... Does anyone has experience with these commands?

I guess I can go around the problem by, for example, checkout the renamed project to another working copy and then overwrite it with the changes (all besides the SVN metadata). I can also write some script that finds all occurrences of the old path and brutally change them to the new paths but I figured there must be some kind of SVN command for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the repository URL changes, you need to **relocate** your working copy. The **switch** command is used to change the branch your working copy points to. The concepts themselves are quite clear.

But you talk about **project** and I guess that's the problem you are facing: you won't find any reference to projects in the Subversion documentation because that isn't a Subversion concept.

There're two basic ways to implement projects in Subversion:

1. Create a repository per project:

   - `https://example.com/svn/foo/trunk`
   - `https://example.com/svn/bar/trunk`
2. Create a branch per project within the same repository:

   - `https://example.com/svn/projects/foo/trunk`
   - `https://example.com/svn/projects/bar/trunk`

So when you say "rename a project" you mean either "rename a repository" (#1) or "rename a branch" (#2) and the solution is:

1. `svn relocate` to link your working copy again with the repository
2. Either `svn update` to bring the changes to your working copy (if the change is within the working copy directory tree) or `svn switch` to change the branch your working copy points to (if you effectively removed current branch).

**Update**: My advice so far is that you start from scratch. Rename your current working copy, check out a fresh one and reapply pending changes with a regular file compare tool like WinMerge or Kdiff3 (or TortoiseMerge). There's no benefit in trying to find out what exact changes you did if they're not evident from the log.

For the future... You don't need to learn the complete Subversion book by heart but you should get to know the basic concepts, esp. when they've proven to be an issue in your daily work.

Comment: Well, I've only renamed a "directory" in the repo tree, which probably mean I've renamed a branch (sorry, I'm a noob at this).

Comment: regarding the svn relocate, it sounds the most suitable action, but I didn't change the URL of the whole repository - only renamed a branch - will it still work well?

Comment: I'm also not sure regarding the svn switch - bear in mind I've made changes in the working copy which I want to commit and I'm afraid of the relations between Update and Switch - would svn switch revert my changes in the working copy? Will it even work if the original branch name does not exist anymore? Would it keep log history etc as usual?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post ("project"-->"branch") and I'm probably going to do it "from scratch" like you've suggested, though it's strange to me that there isn't a specific svn command for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the svn switch..

```
switch --relocate OLDURL TO NEWURL
```

which should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid of using this because I only renamed a branch in my repository and so I'm not sure this suits the recommended scenario upon which you use this command...

Comment: May be you can simply use a simple svn switch NEWURL.